# Time Difference Between Rows with Same ID with Variables

Tags: sql

need to find the time difference between rows with the same id but with some variables.

that is what I came up with so far:

```
SELECT 
  SR_Service_Audit_RecID AS 'id',
  SR_Service_RecID AS 'Ticket Number',
  OldValue_Text AS 'Previous Status',
  NewValue_Text AS 'NEW Status',
  Created_By AS 'Operator',
  CAST(Date_Entered_UTC AS DATETIME) AS 'Date And Time',
  CAST(Date_Entered_UTC - lag(Date_Entered_UTC) over (order by Date_Entered_UTC) AS TIME(0)) as 'Time Difference'
FROM 
  SR_Service_Audit
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjIuN.png)

Comment: Hey Nelson, welcome to SO. You should provide all your specs in the question (not in the image), that way is easier to understand and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The lag() over () function gives already the difference between the current row and the previous one.
If you don't mind droping all intermediate rows, one approach could be (assuming that your SR_Service_Audit log table is already sorted by id and date&time and that there is only one row per service with the mentioned requirements):

```sql
SELECT
  SR_Service_Audit_RecID AS 'id',
  SR_Service_RecID AS 'Ticket Number',
  OldValue_Text AS 'Previous Status',
  NewValue_Text AS 'NEW Status',
  Created_By AS 'Operator',
  CAST(Date_Entered_UTC AS DATETIME) AS 'Date And Time',
  CAST(Date_Entered_UTC - lag(Date_Entered_UTC) over (order by Date_Entered_UTC) AS TIME(0)) as 'Time Difference'
FROM
  SR_Service_Audit
WHERE 
  SR_Service_RecID = NewValue_Text OR (NewValue_Text = 'Awaiting Tech' and Created_By = 'PrincessB')
```

Comment: Hi, yes, that's correct.

What I needed actually was to join the two "Venn diagrams" I want to observe.
eg. 
   diagram A = all new tickets entries 
   diagram B = entries that specify that the new status is "awaiting tech" by the operator "XYZ"

which I could do by using INNER JOIN.

now just need final adjustments.

Thanks for the help!